# Why doesn't this node.js + mongoose code save to the DB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, mongoose

I'm learning Node.js + mongodb using a simple tutorial - the problem is that I can't get it to save().

This is the code I'm running:

```
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

PostSchema = new Schema({
    title: String,
    body: String,
    date: Date
});

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/posterdb');
mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);
var Post = mongoose.model('Post');

// create a post and save it
var post = new Post();

post.title = 'My first post';
post.body = 'Post body';
post.date = Date.now();

post.save(function(err) {
    console.log('error check');
    if(err) { throw err; }
    console.log('saved');
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

It doesn't print anything on the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the connection get established? Try the event `mongoose.connection.on("open", function() { ... })`.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It doesn't get established. mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/posterdb', function(err){   console.log(err);
}); Prints : { stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'failed to connect to [localhost:27017]' }

Comment: Are you sure the server is running at that host and port?

Comment: Indeed, the server wasn't running. Had no data directory by default. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my mongodb server wasn't running because I didn't have a /data/db directory installed by default upon installing mongo in ubuntu. Created that, started the server, everything worked fine. Solved.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone found this question for the same reason I did, then maybe this will help:

Found that I couldn't save a new object to my collection.  I had made a schema method named validate() which interfered with MongoDB's validate() function, so that's why it wasn't saving to the DB and was giving me zero errors.  So don't name a method in your schema entitled validate().  Hopefully my dumbness will save you a lot of time.